# VMWare Horizon Ubuntu Desktop Pool Giving Black Screen After Logon

Tags: 16.04, graphics, vdi, vmware-view

I'm facing a weird problem when connecting to my Ubuntu Desktop virtual machines through the VMware Horizon client on Windows or Ubuntu PC.

Let me describe the issue. I have created a **Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop Pool** on **VMware Horizon 7 View Administrator** panel. I  deployed a few Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 virtual servers from a template on our VCenter earlier and assigned these virtual servers to the desktop pool that I created. The template has Vmware Tools and the Horizon Agent installed on it. I added the Ubuntu VM's to the domain according to the VMware's procedure.

Following all the necessary configurations, I can connect and login to the Ubuntu machines through the VSphere console. However, when I try to connect them through the Horizon Client, I can't login to them. Actually, I can see the login screen and can write my credentials on the screen, but when I hit the "Sign In" button, screen freezes or turns into black. I increased the Video Card Memory size of the VM to 96 MB just to make sure it's not about video memory, but that didn't fix the problem. There are very few resources on the internet about Ubuntu Desktop Pools, so I couldn't find a proper way to solve the issue. I used this page as a general guide for the configurations: https://vmguru.com/2016/05/linux-desktops-horizon/

This is my first question on this platform, so I hope this is the correct place to ask this question.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.